# Installing a package from repositories of an older release on a newer Ubuntu

Tags: apt, repository

Snmpd for Ubuntu 11.10 has some issues, so I want to install snmpd from Ubuntu 10.04 lucid repositories. How can this be done?

Comment: You can also try downloading SNMP source and compile it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please do this at your own risk**

1. Remove SNMPD

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove snmpd
   ```
2. Download this package from lucids repositories

   - 32 bit - [Download from here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/snmpd_5.4.2.1~dfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb)
   - 64 bit - [Download from here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/snmpd_5.4.2.1~dfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb)

The dependencies should be satisfied. Install all of them and you are done.