# Printer driver depends on libbeecrypt7:i386 but it's not in repositories

Tags: drivers, package-management, printing, 16.04, repository

I just did a fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04 and now I'm trying to configure a printer.

The printer is a Canon mf4320d, so I downloaded the driver from manufacturer's website and tried to install it. However, during installation, it says that cannot find neither package libeecrypt7:i386 nor libeecrypt-dev:i386.

I have i386 architecture enabled and I already have installed some i386 packages from repositories, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Also, I installed this same printer on Xubuntu 14.04 with no problems at all.

This packages used to be in universe repository, but they seem to have been removed in the most recent versions of Ubuntu. (note: I have universe repository enabled)

What should I do the best to install the driver? Maybe downloading and installing the packages from previous ubuntu versions repositories?

Thanks!

PD: is there any reason for this packages being removed from repositories?

Edit: my question is not about how to install a package from a previous version repository, my question was if this is a good solution in this case, or if there is another better solution.

Comment: What exactly did you download and how did you (try to) install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing a package from repositories of an older release on a newer Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125831/installing-a-package-from-repositories-of-an-older-release-on-a-newer-ubuntu)

Comment: I downloaded the driver installer from Canon website. The installer's executable script first check for some dependencies that the driver needs, and install the missing ones using apt-get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beecrypt` has been [removed from Debian](https://packages.qa.debian.org/b/beecrypt/news/20160406T050508Z.html), and thus from Ubuntu as well, due to it being unmaintained by its developers and not used by any other package in Debian.

Hopefully Canon will soon provide a package which does not depend on it, but in the meantime it should be fine to install [the Trusty package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libbeecrypt7). You can also try to look for third-party repositories providing a Xenial package.

Comment: I installed the package from the link you provided (and also package libbeecrypt-dev, which is also needed by the printer driver), then executed the driver's installer, and now I do have the printer working.

Comment: The wily package link you provided is broken and I'm unable to find the libbeecrypt7 package for xenial 16.04. Could you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of Canon driver (3.40) depends on "libgcrypt20:i386" and "libgcrypt20-dev:i386" packages. So these packages should be installed instead.

Comment: indeed; use the latest 3.4 from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html as this driver was released on 9th Nov 2017 and I understand Canon hope to release a revision in early 2018 for 17.10 Ubuntu.