# How to install libeecrypt7:i386 from the Wili package?

Tags: drivers, package-management, 16.04, printing, canon

I need install a driver for "Canon MF8330", which is discussed here [Printer driver depends on libbeecrypt7:i386 but it's not in repositories](https://askubuntu.com/q/763171/553684).

I know I need to install  libeecrypt7:i386 from the Wili package, but I don't know how.

Comment: Download the `.deb`-file from this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libbeecrypt7 and open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t, navigate with `cd Download` to the direcotry where you downloaded the package, install it with `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb` where "package-name" is the name of the downloaded package.

Comment: @MadMike you could please move this into an answer and mention that he might have to download the dependencies as well.

Comment: @Videonauth You are right. I thought that I can do it wit apt-get (via command line parameters or editing /etc/apt/sources.list) and it solve dependencies at once.

Comment: @Videonauth Posted the comment as answer

Answer (score 2):

### How to install packages manually

To install the libbeecrypt7 manually open this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libbeecrypt7

[image: download the amd64 or the i386 package]

Download the amd64-package if you have a 64-bit Ubuntu installation (don't worry if you have a intel processor, it will work fine). If not download the i386 package.

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- Navigate to your download folder with `cd Downloads`
- Install the package with `sudo dpkg -i package-name.deb` where "package-name" needs to be replaced with the actual name of the `.deb`-file you just downloaded.

There are two downsides of this method:

- The package might refuse to install due to missing dependecies. Comment to this answer if that is the case.
- Since this package isn't installed from the repository it won't receive any updates. This is a potential security risk.